# Sampler Aggregation in Elasticsearch 2.0.0

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

```
{
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "text": query
                }
            },
            "size": 5,
            "aggs": {
                "bestDocs": {
                    "sampler": {
                        "field": "cluster",
                        "shard_size": 1
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "bestBuckets": {
                            "terms": {
                                "field": "cluster",
                                "size": 5
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Using the simple query I get a bunch of documents where each document has a `bucket` id. I am trying to use sampler aggregation to get the buckets ids in the sequence they appear in the general query.

But when I run the above query I get buckets in ascending order and they are not even the ones that I get from the general query.

E.g.

```
{
    "took": 4,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 959,
        "max_score": 1.841992,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_source": {
                    "cluster": "22570",
                    "text": "about 1.5 million veteran families live at the federal poverty level, including 634,000 below 50 percent of the federal poverty",
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "cluster": "22570",
                    "text": "about 1.5 million veteran families live at the federal poverty level, including 634,000 below 50 percent of the federal poverty",
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "cluster": "22570",
                    "text": "about 1.5 million veteran families live at the federal poverty level, including 634,000 below 50 percent of the federal poverty",
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "cluster": "22570",
                    "text": "about 1.5 million veteran families live at the federal poverty level, including 634,000 below 50 percent of the federal poverty",
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "cluster": "12239",
                    "text": "veterans and their families.&quot;</p><p>The Veterans&#39; Compensation Cost-of-Living Adjustment Act of 2011 directs the Secretary of Veterans Affairs to increase the rates of veterans",
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "bestDocs": {
            "doc_count": 5,
            "bestBuckets": {
                "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
                "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
                "buckets": [
                    {
                        "key": 22185,
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 22570,
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 29615,
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 32784,
                        "doc_count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "key": 43351,
                        "doc_count": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

YOu can see that the aggregation is not what was required. How can I get `[22570, 12239]` in sequence?

Answer (score 0):

```
"sampler": {
    "field": "cluster",
    "shard_size": 1  // <-- It could be the potential culprit
},
```

The IDs `22570, 12239` may both belong to the same shard. As you have specified shard size as 1, the aggregations might have got only one from the shard due to which `12239` got omitted from aggregations.